# How to make default dictionary of default dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to have `default dictionary` of `default dictionaries` with `list`.

Any idea how to make something like this ?

Comment: What exactly is stopping you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own `lambda` function:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```

What is required for the argument to `defaultdict` is just some callable that takes no arguments and returns an object.  In this case, our callable returns a `defaultdict`.